# Where is the crash log of spring boot embedded Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, logging, crash, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 1.3.1 with its embedded Tomcat container. I am new to Spring boot.

I run with as a standalone jar via `java -jar myApp.jar`.

I set the log file and tomcat location in the `application.properties`:

```
logging.file=myApp.log
server.tomcat.basedir=./tomcat
```

However, the app exits quite often QUIETLY. In the log file nothing informative of the exit.

So my question is how to enable some more detailed logging of the application, or is there some method can be used to trouble shooting in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Had you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging via `application.properties` using properties starting with `logging.level`. To enable debug logging for *everything*:

```
logging.level.ROOT=DEBUG
```

Alternatively, you can enable logging for a particular package (and its sub packages). For example:

```
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=DEBUG
```

Comment: I've already set that flag. However, nothing special in the log file. Most of the logs are generated from Spring, not from tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the same package to standalone Tomcat to get the root cause of the failure. 
Exceptions at certain stages of the application startup will stay hidden otherwise.